# How to fix android studio 3.0 logcat log print delay (2-5 mins)?

Tags: android-studio, android-logcat

I have used Android Studio 2.3 before upgrading to version 3.0 this month. But the Logcat print log delay is now 2~5 mins (when it prints I clean the log on console and it stops printing again). How can I fix it? help

Comment: Windows? Mac? Linux? Anyway, restart? Try `sudo killall adb` (if Mac/linux).

Comment: Thx for answer.I run as on Macbook pro 15.It anway delay after i upgrade to 3.0 .`sudo kill all adb ` command not yet excute.I rebooted pc but problem still .

Comment: Remember it’s `sudo killall adb` (not `kill all`). Anyway, not sure what the problem is. I suggest you go back to Android Studio 2.3 and see if you experience the same issue there. What version of Java SDK/Runtime do you have? Did you reboot the device? What device is that?

Comment: have you found any solution? i am still facing it.

Comment: I have back to AS 2.3.It do well on 2.3. it maybe AS3.0 's bug,but nobody ask the question.^.^

Comment: i got this problem too. 

Android Studio 3.0.1 

Mac os version 10.12.6

Comment: I was forced to downgrade from AS 3.0.1 to AS 2.2.2. (Win10)  Please 'star' issue reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70614086).